# unresolved external symbol (LNK2019) when using extern c while testing c file using gtest

Tags: c++, c, googletest, linkage, lnk2019

I am trying to test c code using gtest (with visual studio).
I have two projects under the same solution: a C project and a gtest project using c++.
The code is attached below:

source.c

```
#include "source.h"

int fun(int x)
{
    return x + 1;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

source.h

```
#pragma once
int fun(int);
```

test.cpp (testing project)

```
#include "pch.h"
extern "C" {
#include "../runtest/source.h"
}

TEST(TestCaseName, TestName) {
  EXPECT_EQ(fun(5), 6);
  EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}
```

The following codes doesn't build and returns the following error:

> Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _fun referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall TestCaseName_TestName_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@TestCaseName_TestName_Test@@EAEXXZ) Sample-Test1    D:\dev\C\runtest\Sample-Test1\test.obj  1

If I am changing the include statement at test.cpp to `#include "../runtest/source.c"` - the test runs properly.
I don't think the problem is with the linkage because it can run the c code from the c++ project. But I can't understand why the header is problematic.

Thank you :)

Comment: You do link with the object file generated from `source.c`?

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: How do you build? How is your project set up? Is `source.c` listed in the same *project* as `test.cpp`?

Comment: They are not listed at the same project. I am building the c project and then the gtest.

Comment: My recommendation: Split the `source.c` file into two separate files: One for the `main` function, and one for the `fun` function. Add the second file (with the `fun` function) in ***both*** projects.